# Determinant of Hermitian Tridiagonal Matrix with Constant Upper and Lower Diagonals

Tags: matrices, determinant

I got this equation where the a terms are known but I want to determine a relationship between the b terms (so, no numerical analysis please). I know that the bi terms are real and the a terms are complex. Any help will be great :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This thing is called an *extended continuant*. So [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuant_(mathematics)) and, maybe,  [Google](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=determinant+continuanta&oq=determinant+continuanta&aqs=chrome..69i57.12598j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) are your friends.